# Как получить список всех групп в которых присутствует бот с помощью aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне необходимо получить список всех групп в которых присутствует мой бот на aiogram.

Я знаю что у aiogram есть метод get_Me() также как в самом telegram bot api, однако вызвав его получаю только:

```
{"id": 1559583412, "is_bot": true, "first_name": "Test my code", "username": "formyprojectsBot", "can_join_groups": true, "can_read_all_group_messages": false, "supports_inline_queries": false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Bot API нет метода для получения **всех** групп, в которых состоит бот.

Решение тут только одно: отлавливать хэндлером момент, когда Ваш бот был добавлен в какой-либо чат, получать данные чата и сохранять в базу данных.